# App Script - Copy and past function is moving data to the row below

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have found a script to copy the range data one sheet (Name My Sheet dataBase) to another sheet (Name My Sheet Destiny) in the first cell and than each one after when it runs.

But, when pasting the data range for "#column1 - #column15", it  copy to row A3 instead of to past to row A2 because in the #column17 i need the formula to calculate the due date of when data it copied.

I did get to explain what is happening and what I need to do to adjust the function?

Thanks.

[image]

```
const app      = SpreadsheetApp;
const ss       = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheet1   = ss.getSheetByName("Name My Sheet dataBase");
const lastrowD = sheet1.getLastRow();
const dados    = sheet1.getRange("A2:O" + lastrowD).getValues();
const ssB      = app.openById("ID My Sheet Destiny");
const sheetB   = ssB.getSheetByName("Name My Sheet Destiny");
const lastrowB = sheetB.getLastRow()+1;

sheetB.getRange(lastrowB, 1, lastrowD - 1, 15).setValues(dados);
```

Comment: sheetD is undefined

Comment: How are you executing your function. Manually or with a trigger?

Comment: Sorry @Cooper, sheetD is sheet1

Comment: @Cooper manually

Comment: Hi @Cooper,

And here I am.

I have tried to apply the recommendations, but the range of data continues being pushed to row A3 when there is a function in the #column17.

So now I'm trying to have created the timestamp and include in #column16 and #column17.

In #column16 I want to include the date the copy of the range of the database (sheet1) and in #column17 the interval of one year the date in #column16 (expiration of the initial period).

Comment: @Cooper I had thought maybe use onEdit()  to timestamp in #column16, but how to do  succeeds when data is pasted? can you help me?

Comment: I would just calculate the due data in script and put it there rather than using a formula

Comment: @Cooper yes and it is my goal. Anyway, thanks so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:  I'm not sure what you doing wrong. I just find it easier to do it my way.

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Name My Sheet dataBase");
  const vs = sh.getRange("A2:O" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID My Sheet Destiny");
  const dsh = dss.getSheetByName("Name My Sheet Destiny");
  dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

- [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Range.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

You could also use the Sheets API

```
function myfunk1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("srcsheet");
  const rg = sh.getRange("A2:O").getA1Notation();
  const vs = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ss.getId(),`${sh.getName()}!${rg}`).values;
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("dssid");
  const dsh = dss.getSheetByName("destsheet");
  const drg = dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1).getA1Notation();
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({ values: vs }, ss.getId(), `${dsh.getName()}!${drg}`, { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" })
}
```

- [Using Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values)

Answer (score 0):

I tried it this way and it worked! <3

Instead of using OnEdit and to set it up to run on a trigger, I created a date object inside SetValues: for the day of registration and another for the expiration date.

```
 function saveControl() {

 const app = SpreadsheetApp;
 const ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 const sheetD = ss.getSheetByName("sheetD name");
 const lastrowD = sheetD.getLastRow();
 const dados = sheetD.getRange("A2:O" + lastrowD).getValues();

 const ssB = app.openById("sheetB ID");
 const sheetB = ssB.getSheetByName("SheetB name");
 const lastrowB = sheetB.getLastRow()+1;

 sheetB.getRange(lastrowB,  4, lastrowD - 1, 15).setValues(dados);
 sheetB.getRange(2, 3, sheetB.getLastRow()-1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-03:00", "dd/MM/yyyy"));
 sheetB.getRange(2, 2, sheetB.getLastRow()-1).setValue(new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 1)));
 }
```

• [Dates and times](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates?hl=pt-br)
• [Class utilities](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities?hl=pt-br#formatdatedate-timezone-format)